# Capybara and Rails, Why has_link? always returns false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I am trying to test with has_link? in my spec test, here is my test:

```
page.has_link?('next_page', {}).should == true
```

but, the test always fail, although the link with id 'next_page' dose exist!
the strange thing is that have_content always works fine, here is how I implement it:

```
page.should have_content("some text")
```

Can you help me please ? what I am missing here ?

**EDIT**

Here is the resulted link in the page:

```
<a id="next_page" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="javascript: void(0)" style="color: #888888">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should do :

page.has_link? "next_page"

or

page.has_link? "next_page", url_path

Answer (score 1):

You can try below sample -

```
it "should have logout link" do
  expect(page).to have_link('Logout') 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this with:

```
rendered.should have_link("Teams", :href => teams_path)
```